# How to use Pattern matching in a Swift for loop for nested array

Tags: swift

For a simple for loop we can use pattern matching like this

```
let arr1 = ["a", true, 1, 5.0]
for case let str as String in arr1 {
    print(str)
}
```

How to get the string from a nested array without nested for loop?

```
let arr2 = [["a", true, 1, 5.0],
            ["b", true, 2, 15.0], 
            ["c", false, 31, 12.0]]
```

The inner array's first object is string always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really *pattern matching* but without a loop

```
arr2.compactMap{$0.first{$0 is String}}.forEach{print($0)}
```

`compactMap` is necessary because `first` returns an optional. The position of the `String` in the array is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using `arr2.compactMap { $0.first as? String }`. But I thought there will be a solution in pattern matching

Comment: Why? Even in your one-dimensional example `first` is more efficient than pattern matching.

Comment: I thought I could do something like this `for case let str = obj.first as String in arr2 {
    print(str)
}`

Comment: Or something like this in one line `for obj in arr2, let str = obj.first as? String {
            print(str)
        }`

Comment: Be aware that unlike `first` a loop (besides pattern matching) evaluates always **all** objects of the array.

Comment: I'm just trying to find all the possible ways to get the string array and choose the simplest one

Comment: Better look for the most efficient one which is not necessarily the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the compact map function if you know that the first object of your array is string and you are interested only for your first item.

**Example:**

```
let arr2 = [["a", true, 1, 5.0],
            ["b", true, 2, 15.0],
            ["c", false, 31, 12.0]]

printStrings(strArrayOfArray: arr2)

func printStrings(strArrayOfArray: [[Any]]) {
print(strArrayOfArray.compactMap({ (anyArray) -> String? in
    if let str = strArrayOfArray.first?.first as? String {
        return str
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}))
```

}

**Output:**

```
["a", "a", "a"]
```

Comment: So can't do this **without nested for loop**?

Comment: Do you want to do it without loop?

Comment: Yes. Check my question again